# Fail to load endpoint class

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After upgrade to AppEngine 1.8.3, some requests to Endpoints starts razing some Warning Exceptions:

com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigLoader loadConfiguration: Fail to load endpoint class class com.Xxxx...
with ApiConfigSource class com.google.api.server.spi.config.datastore.ApiConfigDatastoreReader

Screenshot:
[image: S]

The request completes normally with http 200 status, and everything goes ok, but it takes too long to finish the request, increasing around 10 to 20 seconds, producing one warning for each Endpoint class (com.Xxxx...).

Its aleatory, sometimes happens, sometimes not.

Any Idea what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per google guys, you can ignore this warning. It's a 1.8.3 bug. "The message shouldn't be appearing, and will be correctly hidden in a future release" https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9824